# Subtotaling with Ranges and Limited Compatibility

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

On SQL Server 2008 R2, I am trying to create a stored procedure that will give the user subtotals of commodities based on their inputted range. I would appreciate any assistance.

However, I ran into a problem in which the query displays All commodities that are being calculated so the user ends with values that will eventually exceed their inputted range. I'll include some sample data on the bottom as well as what I have tried.

Here's an example (that I took out some columns in for clarity in this example):

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfQ8e.png)

As you can tell, for a range between 2000 and 10000, commodity 998-32 is going to exceed 10000 in subtotals but still displays since each PO NO is individually less than 10000.

Here is some sample data:

```
DROP TABLE ##mytable;
CREATE TABLE ##mytable(
   Commodity             VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
  ,PO_NO                 INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,LINE_NO               INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,PO_Line_Description   VARCHAR(82)
  ,Commodity_Description VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
  ,Fiscal_Year           INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Vendor_ID             INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Vendor_Name           VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,QUANTITY              INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,UNIT_COST             NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL
  ,Line_Amount           NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO ##mytable(Commodity,PO_NO,LINE_NO,PO_Line_Description,Commodity_Description,Fiscal_Year,Vendor_ID,Vendor_Name,QUANTITY,UNIT_COST,Line_Amount) VALUES ('998-18',1448923,1,'Face Scholastic book order attached.','Sale of Surplus and Obsolete Books',2015,47650,'SCHOLASTIC INC',1,9999.8,9999.8);
INSERT INTO ##mytable(Commodity,PO_NO,LINE_NO,PO_Line_Description,Commodity_Description,Fiscal_Year,Vendor_ID,Vendor_Name,QUANTITY,UNIT_COST,Line_Amount) VALUES ('998-32',1416311,2,'First 12 months maintenance agreement to be billed quarterly at .0039 per b/w copy','Sale of Surplus and Obsolete Copy Machines',2015,341479,'RICOH USA, INC',1,5148,5148);
INSERT INTO ##mytable(Commodity,PO_NO,LINE_NO,PO_Line_Description,Commodity_Description,Fiscal_Year,Vendor_ID,Vendor_Name,QUANTITY,UNIT_COST,Line_Amount) VALUES ('998-32',1424377,1,NULL,'Sale of Surplus and Obsolete Copy Machines',2015,300590,'KONICA MINOLTA/ CIT',1,2894.58,2894.58);
INSERT INTO ##mytable(Commodity,PO_NO,LINE_NO,PO_Line_Description,Commodity_Description,Fiscal_Year,Vendor_ID,Vendor_Name,QUANTITY,UNIT_COST,Line_Amount) VALUES ('998-32',1404031,1,'1st (12) months of (36) month Lease payment for (1) MPC4503 copier.','Sale of Surplus and Obsolete Copy Machines',2015,341479,'RICOH USA, INC',1,2050.68,2050.68);
INSERT INTO ##mytable(Commodity,PO_NO,LINE_NO,PO_Line_Description,Commodity_Description,Fiscal_Year,Vendor_ID,Vendor_Name,QUANTITY,UNIT_COST,Line_Amount) VALUES ('998-75',1401552,1,'Blanket order for 50 teachers - each teacher not to exceed $100.00.','Sale of Surplus and Obsolete Paper and Paper Products',2015,27536,'KNOWLEDGE TREE',1,5000,5000);
INSERT INTO ##mytable(Commodity,PO_NO,LINE_NO,PO_Line_Description,Commodity_Description,Fiscal_Year,Vendor_ID,Vendor_Name,QUANTITY,UNIT_COST,Line_Amount) VALUES ('998-78',1521390,1,'PL02286>PRESSURE PLUMBER INSTANT DRAIN OPENER 24 SHOT CARTRIDGE','Sale of Surplus and Obsolete Plumbing Equipment and Supplies',2015,402985,'TECH MECH SUPPLY LLC',480,8,3840);
```

I have tried using a SUM() OVER (PARTITION BY [   ] ORDER BY [   ] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) but apparently that the OVER clause with a ROW was introduced in SQL Server 2012 and does not work with 2008 R2.

I have also tried using GROUP BY ROLLUP but I get a message that says "The CUBE() and ROLLUP() grouping constructs are not allowed in the current compatibility mode.  They are only allowed in 100 mode or higher." When I asked our DBA, he said we can't move to 100 mode from 90 mode because a lot of things will break.

So now I'm stuck with the below query, which has the problem stated earlier, the issue of giving me the data I want but also the subtotals of data that will eventually exceed my specified range.

P.S. I have also noticed that if the commodity has PO NOs that are within my selected range but also PO NOs with costs outside of it, this query will give me those within the selected range which is very misleading since it is still a commodity that will be outside the selected range if it were all calculated. They shouldn't be listed into the results at all with the commodities that are truly within my selected range.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[POreport] (
    @Param1 INT
    ,@Param2 INT
    ,@Param3 INT
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY T.Product_ID
                ,T.PO_NO
                ,T.LINE_NO
            ) AS [RowID]
        ,ISNULL(T.PRODUCT_ID, 'NULL') AS [Commodity]
        ,ISNULL(T.PO_NO, 'NULL') AS [PO NO]
        ,ISNULL(T.LINE_NO, 'NULL') AS [LINE NO]
        ,QUOTENAME(T.DESCRIPTION, '"') AS [PO Line Description]
        ,QUOTENAME(C.DESCRIPTION, '"') AS [Commodity Description]
        ,ISNULL(T.FY, 'NULL') AS [Fiscal Year]
        ,PH.Vendor_ID AS [Vendor ID]
        ,QUOTENAME(V.Vendor_Name, '"') AS [Vendor Name]
        ,T.QUANTITY
        ,T.UNIT_COST
        ,T.QUANTITY * T.UNIT_COST AS [Line Amount]
        ,(
            SELECT CAST(0.00 AS NUMERIC(10, 2))
            ) AS Sub_Total_Cost
    INTO ##TmpPOReport
    FROM dbo.DBVW_FI_REQ_PO_ITEMS T
    INNER JOIN dbo.FI_VENDOR FV ON T.INST_ID = FV.INST_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.FI_REQ_PO_HEADER PH ON T.PO_NO = PH.PO_NO
    INNER JOIN dbo.FI_VENDOR V ON PH.VENDOR_ID = V.VENDOR_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.FI_COMMODITY C ON T.PRODUCT_ID = C.FI_COMMODITY_CODE
    WHERE T.INST_ID = 'SC00'
        AND T.FY = @Param1
        AND V.VENDOR_TYPE = 'V'
        AND T.PO_NO IS NOT NULL
        AND (
            T.PRODUCT_ID <> ''
            AND T.PRODUCT_ID IS NOT NULL
            )
        AND T.QUANTITY * T.UNIT_COST BETWEEN @Param2
            AND @Param3
    GROUP BY T.PRODUCT_ID
        ,T.PO_NO
        ,T.LINE_NO
        ,T.DESCRIPTION
        ,C.DESCRIPTION
        ,T.FY
        ,PH.Vendor_ID
        ,V.Vendor_Name
        ,T.QUANTITY
        ,T.UNIT_COST
        ,PH.Created_Date
    ORDER BY Commodity

    DECLARE @PID VARCHAR(15) = 00
        ,@QUANTITY INT
        ,@UNIT_COST NUMERIC(10, 2)
        ,@PrevID VARCHAR(15)
        ,@RowID BIGINT
        ,@PrevRowID BIGINT
        ,@RowAmount NUMERIC(10, 2)
        ,@SubTotal NUMERIC(10, 2) = 0.00

    SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;

    WHILE EXISTS (
            SELECT TOP 1 *
            FROM ##TmpPOReport
            WHERE Sub_Total_Cost = 0.00
            )
    BEGIN
        SET @RowAmount = (
                SELECT TOP 1 (QUANTITY * UNIT_COST)
                FROM ##TmpPOReport
                WHERE Sub_Total_Cost = 0.00
                )

        SELECT TOP 1 @PID = Commodity
            ,@RowID = RowID
        FROM ##TmpPOReport
        WHERE Sub_Total_Cost = 0.00

        IF (@PID = @PrevID)
            AND (@RowID <> @PrevRowID)
        BEGIN
            SET @SubTotal += @RowAmount;

            UPDATE T
            SET Sub_Total_Cost = @SubTotal
            FROM ##TmpPOReport T
            WHERE T.Commodity = @PID
                AND RowID = @RowID

            SET @PrevID = @PID;
            SET @PrevRowID = @RowID
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @SubTotal = @RowAmount;

            UPDATE T
            SET Sub_Total_Cost = @SubTotal
            FROM ##TmpPOReport T
            WHERE T.Commodity = @PID
                AND RowID = @RowID

            SET @PrevID = @PID;
            SET @PrevRowID = @RowID
        END
    END

    SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON;

    SELECT *
    FROM ##TmpPOReport
    WHERE [Line Amount] BETWEEN @Param2
            AND @Param3

    DROP TABLE ##TmpPOReport
END
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is not clear. If you want to duplicate the `SUM OVER ROWS` then you will need to use a CTE or similar sub query below. This is not an optimized query but it will give you the running sum over commodity. It uses `RANK() OVER PARTITION` to get an instance or row number per PO within a commodity.

```
    DECLARE @mytable TABLE(
       Commodity             VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
      ,PO_NO                 INTEGER  NOT NULL
      ,LINE_NO               INTEGER  NOT NULL
      ,PO_Line_Description   VARCHAR(82)
      ,Commodity_Description VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
      ,Fiscal_Year           INTEGER  NOT NULL
      ,Vendor_ID             INTEGER  NOT NULL
      ,Vendor_Name           VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
      ,QUANTITY              INTEGER  NOT NULL
      ,UNIT_COST             NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL
      ,Line_Amount           NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL
    );
    INSERT INTO @mytable(Commodity,PO_NO,LINE_NO,PO_Line_Description,Commodity_Description,Fiscal_Year,Vendor_ID,Vendor_Name,QUANTITY,UNIT_COST,Line_Amount) VALUES ('998-18',1448923,1,'Face Scholastic book order attached.','Sale of Surplus and Obsolete Books',2015,47650,'SCHOLASTIC INC',1,9999.8,9999.8);
    INSERT INTO @mytable(Commodity,PO_NO,LINE_NO,PO_Line_Description,Commodity_Description,Fiscal_Year,Vendor_ID,Vendor_Name,QUANTITY,UNIT_COST,Line_Amount) VALUES ('998-32',1416311,2,'First 12 months maintenance agreement to be billed quarterly at .0039 per b/w copy','Sale of Surplus and Obsolete Copy Machines',2015,341479,'RICOH USA, INC',1,5148,5148);
    INSERT INTO @mytable(Commodity,PO_NO,LINE_NO,PO_Line_Description,Commodity_Description,Fiscal_Year,Vendor_ID,Vendor_Name,QUANTITY,UNIT_COST,Line_Amount) VALUES ('998-32',1424377,1,NULL,'Sale of Surplus and Obsolete Copy Machines',2015,300590,'KONICA MINOLTA/ CIT',1,2894.58,2894.58);
    INSERT INTO @mytable(Commodity,PO_NO,LINE_NO,PO_Line_Description,Commodity_Description,Fiscal_Year,Vendor_ID,Vendor_Name,QUANTITY,UNIT_COST,Line_Amount) VALUES ('998-32',1404031,1,'1st (12) months of (36) month Lease payment for (1) MPC4503 copier.','Sale of Surplus and Obsolete Copy Machines',2015,341479,'RICOH USA, INC',1,2050.68,2050.68);
    INSERT INTO @mytable(Commodity,PO_NO,LINE_NO,PO_Line_Description,Commodity_Description,Fiscal_Year,Vendor_ID,Vendor_Name,QUANTITY,UNIT_COST,Line_Amount) VALUES ('998-75',1401552,1,'Blanket order for 50 teachers - each teacher not to exceed $100.00.','Sale of Surplus and Obsolete Paper and Paper Products',2015,27536,'KNOWLEDGE TREE',1,5000,5000);
    INSERT INTO @mytable(Commodity,PO_NO,LINE_NO,PO_Line_Description,Commodity_Description,Fiscal_Year,Vendor_ID,Vendor_Name,QUANTITY,UNIT_COST,Line_Amount) VALUES ('998-78',1521390,1,'PL02286>PRESSURE PLUMBER INSTANT DRAIN OPENER 24 SHOT CARTRIDGE','Sale of Surplus and Obsolete Plumbing Equipment and Supplies',2015,402985,'TECH MECH SUPPLY LLC',480,8,3840);


    DECLARE @FiscalYear INT
    DECLARE @LowTotalCost INT
    DECLARE @HighTotalCost INT

    SET @FiscalYear=2015
    SET @LowTotalCost=1000
    SET @HighTotalCost=10000




SELECT
    *
FROM
(       

    SELECT Commodity,PO_NO,QUANTITY,UNIT_COST,Line_Amount,
        RunningTotal=
        (
            SELECT SUM(TotalCost) FROM 
            (
                SELECT Commodity,TotalCost =(MT.QUANTITY * MT.UNIT_COST),
                    Instance=RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY Commodity ORDER BY Commodity,PO_NO DESC)
                FROM 
                    @mytable MT
                WHERE
                    (MT.QUANTITY * MT.UNIT_COST) BETWEEN @LowTotalCost AND @HighTotalCost
                    AND
                    (MT.Fiscal_Year=@FiscalYear)
            )AS Y 
            WHERE
                (Y.Commodity=X.Commodity) AND(Y.Instance<=X.Instance)
        )
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Commodity,PO_NO,QUANTITY,UNIT_COST,Line_Amount,
            TotalCost = (MT.QUANTITY * MT.UNIT_COST),
            Instance=RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY Commodity ORDER BY Commodity,PO_NO DESC)
        FROM 
            @mytable MT
        WHERE
            --IS FILTER HERE -->(MT.QUANTITY * MT.UNIT_COST) BETWEEN @LowTotalCost AND @HighTotalCost
            --AND
            (MT.Fiscal_Year=@FiscalYear)
    )AS X
)AS Z
WHERE

    (Commodity IN   
    (
        SELECT Commodity FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                Commodity, 
                Total=SUM(QUANTITY * UNIT_COST) 
            FROM 
                @mytable mt2 
            WHERE 
                mt2.Fiscal_Year=@FiscalYear 
            GROUP BY 
                Commodity 
        )AS A
        WHERE
            A.Total BETWEEN @LowTotalCost AND @HighTotalCost
    )
    )
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    @mytable MT
```

Comment: From what I see of the results using your's, it gives me the same thing as mine above does: http://puu.sh/kYgYq/1f5bc85410.png Which runs into the same misleading problem. If I am selecting a range for commodities, it will give me the incomplete running total. For example,  when I select for commodities between 1000 to 10000, commodity 998-32 will show me 8042.58 and 2894.58 when 998-32 is really 10093.26 (over 10000). Is there a way to add a column that is the highest running total amount of each commodity for each commodity so I can select my range off that? Thanks.

Comment: I added a final WHERE clause on  Commodity IN() to support the problem in your comment. However, at this point I would convert and use CTE as it will be far more readable.

Comment: After testing it out, the running totals seemed to be working. However, I did notice that it was adding subtotals of commodities if the commodity number were the same without any regard to fiscal year. For example, for commodity 035-10, it would add all the running totals regardless of 2014 or 2015 or 2016 as fiscal year. Is there a way to separate the running totals to both fiscal year and commodity so that it would be running totals for 035-10 at 2014 and 035-10 at 2015, etc?

Comment: Or a way to group the running totals to fiscal year and commodity?